# Can we show Y-Axis value of Chart as String value in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

In my scenario For Y-Axis value show as string value like "NA". But My Data return correct data. But Chart is not visible. its loading still.

http://jsfiddle.net/3ajw61ze/2/

$(function () {

```
// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Basic drilldown'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 1,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        id: 'toplevel',
        name: 'Ratio',
        data: [
            {name: 'Income', y: 'NA',color:'Green', drilldown: null},
            {name: 'Expenses',  y: 'NA',color:'Red', drilldown: null},
            {name: 'NetProfit', y: 'NA',color:'Orange', drilldown: null}
        ]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: null
    }
})
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts requires `x` and `y` values to be numbers. To solve your problem you can use `category` axis type:

```
yAxis: {
    categories: ['NA']
},
series: [{
    ...,
    data: [{
            y: 0,
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/spu2gfwn/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.type